# Insert Line Break into Excel Cell with Coldfusion 9

Tags: excel, coldfusion

I'm using Coldfusion 9 to generate an Excel spreadsheet. I'm using the new functions, such as SpreadsheetNew(), SpreadsheetAddRow(), and SpreadsheetSetCellValue().  I'd like to have data in some cells include line breaks within the cell.  I tried this with no luck:

```
<cfset my_spreadsheet = SpreadsheetNew("My Spreadsheet","false")>
<cfset cell_value = "First Line">
<cfset carr = chr(13) & chr(10)>
<cfset cell_value = cell_value & carr & "Second Line">
<cfset SpreadsheetSetCellValue(my_spreadsheet, cell_value, 1, 1)>
```

In the Excel output, row 1 column 1 shows this:

> First LineSecond Line

But I want it to show:

> First Line
> Second Line

Any thoughts? Thanks!!

Comment: Have you tried just using chr(10) in stead of 10 and 13 ?

Comment: No luck with just 10 or just 13.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to adjust the cell format to enable line wrapping

```
<cfset sheet = SpreadsheetNew("My Spreadsheet")>
<cfset SpreadsheetSetCellValue(sheet, "foo"& chr(10) &"bar", 1, 1)>
<cfset SpreadsheetFormatCell(sheet, {textwrap=true}, 1, 1)>
```